# jQuery Drag & Drop Simulate Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, simulate

Thank you in advance for taking a look at this! I am having trouble simulating the drag & drop feature provided by jQuery UI via the extended plugin found here:

https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext/blob/master/doc/drag-n-drop.md

The documentation uses the following to which I modified to suite my needs:

```
$('#draggableDiv').simulate("drag", {dragTarget: otherDiv});

Changed to this:
$('#placeme').simulate("drag", {dragTarget: $("#page1")});
```

My alert message never pops up, therefore it is evident that the drop function is never fired, I'm not sure why. Manually dragging the object to page1 behaves normally.

JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/d2fdvxhz/8/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="view-port">
        <div id="placeme" class="droppableShape">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6f/Smiley_Face.png" width="25" height="25" />
        </div>
        <button id="testme">Simulate Drop</button>
        <div class="page" id="page1" style="background-image: url(http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2012-08-15-1CanvasPanelInstall5psd.jpg);"></div>
        <!-- Pages Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".droppableShape").draggable({
            helper:'clone'
     });

    $(".page").droppable({
        accept: ".droppableShape",
        tolerance: 'fit',
        drop: function(event,ui){
            alert("Drop Detected");

            var new_field = $(ui.helper).clone().removeClass('droppableShape');
            var droppable_page = $(this);
            var droppableOffset = $(this).offset();
            new_field.css('top', ui.position.top - droppableOffset.top);
            new_field.css('left', ui.position.left - droppableOffset.left);

            // Set Draggable Options
            new_field.draggable({
                containment: droppable_page,
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    // Save position after dragging stops
                    $(this).data("x_cord", ui.position.left);
                    $(this).data("y_cord", ui.position.top);
                    $(this).draggable( "disable" );
                }
            });

            // Add to drop area
            $(this).append(new_field);
        }
    });

    $( "#testme" ).click(function() {
        $('#placeme').simulate("drag", {
            dragTarget: $("#page1")
        });
        console.log("Simulate Attempted");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
$('#placeme').simulate("drag-n-drop", {
```

As documented [here](https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext/blob/master/doc/drag-n-drop.md#drag-n-drop)

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2fdvxhz/10/)

If you simulate just a drag, a drop never occurs

Comment: Thanks for the help! This worked in the fiddle, trying to apply this to my real project as I could not post the source code. Really appreciate your time.